# Closing dropdown menu once page is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu of a few different pages.  I'm trying to get it so that when you click on a page the menu dropdown menu will close.  Right now the dropdown menu stays open until you hover off of it.  So for example, if you select "hair" the menu will close, instead of staying open.

Also not apart of this question, but if anyone has a solution I would really appreciate it.  The dropdown menu lists the all page twice if the all page is currently selected.  Is there a way to only show all once if selected?

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/z7dg5e0n/1/

```js
jQuery(".shop-beauty-span").html("All");
jQuery("#ShopBeautyPage1").show();

jQuery(".shop-beauty-li").on('click', function() {
  var value = jQuery(this).val();
  if (value) {
    jQuery(".shopbeautypage").hide();
    jQuery("#ShopBeautyPage" + value).show();
   jQuery(".shop-beauty-span").html($(this).text());
  }
});
```

```css
.shop-beauty-ul{
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
width:100%;
  text-align:center;
    min-width:200px;
}

.shopbeautypage{
  display:none;
}

#shop-beauty-drop:hover > ul{
  display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#shop-beauty-drop:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#shop-beauty-drop{
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 22%;
  text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    min-width:200px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'textaw00-heavyregular', 'AvenirNextLTW01', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.shop-beauty-li{
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.shop-beauty-li:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shop-beauty-drop">
  <span class="shop-beauty-span"></span>
  <ul class="shop-beauty-ul">
    <li class="shop-beauty-li" value="1">All</li>
    <li class="shop-beauty-li" value="2">Hair</li>
    <li class="shop-beauty-li" value="3">Makeup</li>  
    <li class="shop-beauty-li" value="4">Skin</li>  
    <li class="shop-beauty-li" value="5">Under $100</li>  
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="ShopBeautyPage1" class="shopbeautypage" style="">
  Content of page 1
</div>
<div id="ShopBeautyPage2" class="shopbeautypage" style="display:none">
  Content of page 2
</div>
<div id="ShopBeautyPage3" class="shopbeautypage" style="display:none">
  Content of page 3
</div>
<div id="ShopBeautyPage4" class="shopbeautypage" style="display:none">
  Content of page 4
</div>
<div id="ShopBeautyPage5" class="shopbeautypage" style="display:none">
  Content of page 5
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using CSS `:hover` you can do everything with jQuery.

I changed your code this way and it seems working to me.

```js
function open() { jQuery(this).toggleClass('open', true); }
function close() { jQuery(this).toggleClass('open', false); }
jQuery("#shop-beauty-drop").hover(open, close);

jQuery(".shop-beauty-span").html("All");
jQuery("#ShopBeautyPage1").show();

jQuery(".shop-beauty-li").on('click', function() {
  var value = jQuery(this).val();

  // The second part of your question
  jQuery(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  
  if (value) {
    jQuery(".shopbeautypage").hide();
    jQuery("#ShopBeautyPage" + value).show();
    jQuery(".shop-beauty-span").html($(this).text());
  }
  
 jQuery("#shop-beauty-drop").trigger("mouseout");
});
```

```css
.shop-beauty-ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.shopbeautypage {
  display: none;
}

#shop-beauty-drop.open > ul {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#shop-beauty-drop:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#shop-beauty-drop {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 22%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 200px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'textaw00-heavyregular', 'AvenirNextLTW01', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.shop-beauty-li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

/* the second part of your question */
.shop-beauty-li.active { display: none; }

.shop-beauty-li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shop-beauty-drop">
  <span class="shop-beauty-span"></span>
  <ul class="shop-beauty-ul">
    <li class="shop-beauty-li active" value="1">All</li>
    <li class="shop-beauty-li" value="2">Hair</li>
    <li class="shop-beauty-li" value="3">Makeup</li>
    <li class="shop-beauty-li" value="4">Skin</li>
    <li class="shop-beauty-li" value="5">Under $100</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="ShopBeautyPage1" class="shopbeautypage" style="">
  Content of page 1
</div>
<div id="ShopBeautyPage2" class="shopbeautypage" style="display:none">
  Content of page 2
</div>
<div id="ShopBeautyPage3" class="shopbeautypage" style="display:none">
  Content of page 3
</div>
<div id="ShopBeautyPage4" class="shopbeautypage" style="display:none">
  Content of page 4
</div>
<div id="ShopBeautyPage5" class="shopbeautypage" style="display:none">
  Content of page 5
</div>
```

Here is also a fork of your fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadm/eL4j33ct/

**Edit** The second part of your question is also solved.

Hope it helps